# Hibernate transaction lock for table having foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql, hibernate, transactions

table 1 with a primary key

table2 has foreign key reference to table1 primary key

I want to insert multiple records to table2

like below code

```
begin hibernate transaction;

OBJ1 = insert table1 object.

loop:

set table2 object with foreignkey OBJ1 and with some other values;

Lock  this object (sothat nobody can insert these values into table2)

loop ends;

commit transaction;
```

Here my problem is actually that foreign key is unique for each transaction, means, that value will be unique for each customer.
i want to lock the other values like seat num etc from entering, by some other customer. 
Since that foreign key is differnt for each customer locking has no purpose .

How can i do the locking here. ?

Iam not posting code her because i didnt write code, i want to plan how can i do this before start codeing.
Please help.

Comment: It is not about `java` or `hibernate`

Comment: @Andremoniy ok, you read the question? any updates?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to prevent inserts in table 2 you can use a unique constraint on that table like a seat number + event. That would effectively fail your commits if someone else picked those items while you were thinking. 
Not the best user friendly strategy.
You'd rather fix your tags not to confuse people with java/hibernate.